# users.search resturns only Creator users in ArcGIS Python API

Tags: arcgis-python-api

I am trying to search for all the users in Portal (10.9.1). I find that it only returns Creator users. I am looking for all the users. The query below uses wildcard.

```py
users = arcgis.gis.UserManager(gis)

allUsers = users.search(query = '*', max_users = 100000)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
from arcgis.gis import GIS

## connect to portal
portal = GIS("home")

## get all users as objects in a list
users = portal.users.search(max_users=1000)

## iterate through the list and print username, license type and role
for user in users:
    print(user["username"], user["userLicenseTypeId"], user["role"])
```